# Discord bot message longer than 2K python

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I used this command

```
@bot.command()
async def allroles(ctx):
    role_names = [role.name for role in ctx.author.roles]
    if "Admin" in role_names or "Mod" in role_names or "Princess" in role_names or "Golden Retriever" in role_names or "Poro" in role_names:
        output2 = ""
        server = ctx.message.guild

        for role in server.roles:
            if role.name == "@everyone":
                output2 += ""
            else:
                output2 += f"{role.name} has {len(role.members)} member in it.  \n"
        await ctx.send(output2)
    else:
        await ctx.send('You don´t have permission to use this command')
```

but since we have more roles it won´t print it

```
Form Body
In content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length.
```

is there any option how to send 2 messages when it´s higher than 2k or to make it as picture? or I don´t know what else can do it to send it.

Thanks!

Comment: the `content` argument for `send()` has to be fewer than 2000 chars. You need to split up the messages you are sending. There are lots of ways to do this.

Comment: I wonder how to split that :/

Comment: I recommend you try something then edit your question. My first hunch would be to check the size of the string using `len()` before adding more strings to it.

Comment: I guess I should use if x>=1800 (or something less than 2k since if its 1998 it will still pass and after passing it will be 200X so It wont be able to resend so I will do x>=1800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @effprime I rewrote it to this code using len() from https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp
Where I check if it´s 1800 or less characters and when it´s over 1800 it will send output2 and clear it (start another message) 1800 is because I want to keep it under 2000 and there I am sure that it will be less than 2000.

```
async def allroles(ctx):
    role_names = [role.name for role in ctx.author.roles]
    if "Admin" in role_names or "Mod" in role_names or "Princess" in role_names or "Golden Retriever" in role_names or "Poro" in role_names:
        output2 = ""
        server = ctx.message.guild
        for role in server.roles:
            if role.name == "@everyone":
              output2 += ""
            else:
              x = len(output2)
              if x>=1800:
                await ctx.send(output2)
                output2 =""
              output2 += f"{role.name} has {len(role.members)} member in it.  \n"
            
              
              
        await ctx.send(output2)
    else:
        await ctx.send('You don´t have permission to use this command')
```